#  Register an instance in config with Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

How to register an instance in config file

I am having this code:

```
UnityContainer.RegisterInstance<ICache>(new CacheMng(HttpRuntime.Cache));
```

And trying to have the equivalent in a config file

```
<register type="ICache" mapTo="CacheMng">
    <lifetime type="Singleton"/>
    <constructor>
        <param name="cache" type="System.Web.Caching" value="HttpRuntime.Cache"/>
    </constructor>>
</register>
```

My CacheMng class has this constructor

```
public CacheMng(Cache cache)
{
    this._cache = cache
}
```

I'm getting this error

> The type name or alias System.Web.Caching could not be resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the error message you see is that the `type` parameter requires a type name and not a namespace name. `System.Web.Caching` is a namespace and not a type.

The only way to do this is to write a custom type converter and use the `value` element, like this:

```
<constructor>
    <param name="cache">
        <value value="" typeConverter="MyHttpRuntimeCacheConverter" />
    </param>
</constructor>
```

The type converter looks something like this (in its simplest form):

```
public class MyHttpRuntimeCacheConverter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
                                     CultureInfo culture, object value,
                                     Type destinationType)
    {
        return HttpRuntime.Cache;
    }
}
```

You could make this more generally applicable by actually providing a value for the Unity `value` element (for example: `System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache`) and based on this value have the type converter return the right object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer answer I came up with the idea of create a TypeConverter to access any static property. Here is my implementation:

**TypeConverter Implementation**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EntLibUnity.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an (formatted) string to a reference of a given static member.
    /// The string uses this format: {member}@{assemblyQualifiedName}
    /// For example:
    ///     Version@System.Environment, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    /// </summary>
    public class StringToStaticInstanceTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return (typeof(string) == sourceType) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            string stringValue;
            if (value == null
                || (stringValue = value as string) == null
                || string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)
                || !stringValue.Contains("@")
            )
            {
                return null;
            }

            var stringParts = stringValue.Split('@');
            if (stringParts.Length != 2)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var staticProperty = stringParts[0];
            var assemblyQualifiedName = stringParts[1];
            var staticClassType = Type.GetType(assemblyQualifiedName, true);
            var staticPropertyInfo = staticClassType.GetProperty(staticProperty,
                                                                 BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static |
                                                                 BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
            var staticValue = staticPropertyInfo.GetValue(null, null) ?? base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
            return staticValue;
        }
    }
}
```

An example of usage:
Let suppose the following Interface and concrete implementation:

```
namespace EntLibUnity.UnitySample
{
    public class VersionManager : IVersionManager
    {
        private readonly Version _version;

        public string Version
        {
            get { return _version.ToString(); }
        }

        public VersionManager(Version version)
        {
            _version = version;
        }
    }
}

namespace EntLibUnity.Infrastructure
{
    public interface IVersionManager
    {
        string Version { get; }
    }
}
```

Our concrete version depends on System.Version, so we configure the container to provide this value. In my example I'll using the configuration file for this purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <!-- Using Design-Time Configuration: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660935(v=PandP.20).aspx#format_config -->
  <!-- The Unity Configuration Schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914(v=PandP.20).aspx -->
  <!-- Specifying Types in the Configuration File http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933(v=PandP.20).aspx#_Default_Aliases_and-->

  <alias alias="StringToStaticInstanceTypeConverter" type="EntLibUnity.Extensions.StringToStaticInstanceTypeConverter, EntLibUnity.Extensions" />
  <alias alias="IVersionManager" type="EntLibUnity.Infrastructure.IVersionManager, EntLibUnity.Infrastructure" />
  <alias alias="VersionManager" type="EntLibUnity.UnitySample.VersionManager, EntLibUnity.UnitySample" />

  <container>
    <register type="IVersionManager" mapTo="VersionManager">
      <constructor>
        <param name="version">
          <value value="Version@System.Environment, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" typeConverter="StringToStaticInstanceTypeConverter" />
        </param>
      </constructor>
    </register>
  </container>

</unity>
```

Finally once you've loaded the configuration, you can use as follow:

```
var versionManager = container.Resolve<IVersionManager>();
Console.WriteLine(versionManager.Version);
```

Good luck